# How do I batch create multiple files based on a list of filenames in Windows?

Tags: batch-file

I need to create 500 empty files with names that are contained in filenames.txt, which contains 500 entries, with one line per entry.  How do I do that in Windows?

*Edit:* Clarified the title

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Echo off & chcp 65001 & For /F "Tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type filenames.txt') do type nul >%%a
```

Note: If there are no extensions specified inside filenames.txt, then add it at last of the code.